symbol not found in flat namespace '_bcp_batch'
I'm using pyenv to manage my python versions.
When i use python 3.12.4 or python3.9^, i get this error:
 File "src/pymssql/_pymssql.pyx", line 1, in init pymssql._pymssql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymssql/_mssql.cpython-312-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_bcp_batch'

my script:
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
import bi_pass

v_server = bi_pass.v_server
v_user = bi_pass.v_user
v_password = bi_pass.v_password
v_database = bi_pass.v_database

source_engine = create_engine(f"mssql+pymssql://{v_user}:{v_password}@{v_server}:1433/{v_database}")
source_conn = source_engine.connect()

query = text( """ SELECT * from test""")
result = source_conn.execute(query)

rows = result.fetchall()
source_conn.close()
source_engine.dispose()

I have a Mac m3 chip, how can I fix it?
Thanks

apparently the error comes from the very first line in reference to pymssql creating an engine, apparently this pymssql library is not found. did you try installing it ?
https://pypi.org/project/pymssql/

Yes, the package is installed, on python 3.9 it works fine, above this version it doesn't work

I found a solution:
pip install --pre --no-binary :all: pymssql --no-cache --force

